# how to fill record with elements of a Tree

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree, record

I'm new to Haskell and want to get the values of the leafs of a self-defined Tree into a record. I started with this.

```
data MyTree = A Int | B Int MyTree | C Double | D Double MyTree 

test = B 1 ( B 1( D 0.02(A 2)))


data MyRecord = MyRecord {A, B :: Int, C :: Double, D :: (Int,Double)}
emptyRecord = MyRecord{a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d =(0,0)}
```

Now i started like this:

```
MyTree2MyRecord :: MyTree -> MyRecord
MyTree2MyRecord(A a1) = emptyRecord{a = a1}
MyTree2MyRecord(B b1 myTree) = emptyRecord {b = b1}
MyTree2MyRecord(C c1) = emptyRecord {c = c1}
MyTree2MyRecord(D d1 myTree) = emptyRecord {d = d1}
 where mytree = MyTree2MyRecord -{dont know the recursive call to iterate through the tree and get the values of the leafs}
```

I understand the simple examples like sum up the leafs of a tree etc, but cant figure out a solution for this problem. I would really appreciate a small hint. Thanks guys

Comment: What is it even _supposed_ to do? There are multiple integer values in a tree but only one in `MyRecord`, you need to specify some idea of how to combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

- Function name should start with small case letters. Hence the record data structure should be like this:

`data MyRecord = MyRecord {a, b :: Int, c :: Double, d :: (Int,Double)}`

- And your function name should be like this:

`myTree2MyRecord :: MyTree -> MyRecord`

Now going through your actual code, you seem to be in almost right path. But in order to find the solution, you have to answer some of these questions:

- What exactly does the `Int` denote in `d :: (Int, Double)` ?
- When you are pattern matching for data constructors like `A`, `B` etc., you seem to be assigning the values of the `MyTree` ADT to the record. Think about the recursive case  there. What output do you want for input like this:

`myTree2MyRecord (B 1 (B 1 (A 1)))`

Your current implementation just discards the value of `MyTree` in it:

```
myTree2MyRecord(B b1 myTree) = emptyRecord {b = b1}
```

Instead of discarding *think* what should happen to `myTree` in this case. This will lead to a recursive solution.

And finally, formulate what output do you want for the input which you have given for the question:

```
test = B 1 ( B 1( D 0.02(A 2)))
```

Once you answer these question, I think you will refactor the code and solve this problem yourself.

Comment: got it. I have done it with a help function like myTree2MyRecord myTree  = fun_help myTree (0,0,0,(0,0)) and than covering each case of it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3588998 Glad that you solved it. Also look on your `MyTree` closely. In case you don't use some type in it, it's better to remove them or use in your logic appropriately.